# Accessing array element from twig function? (Symfony)

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I want to do the equivalent of accessing:

```
{{ user.getRoles()[0]['name'] }}
```

So `user.getRoles()` is an array, and I want to access the `name` element of the first item in the array.

Obviously the above doesn't work though (error `Impossible to access a key "name"`) I assume because combining the function call and accessing an array element isn't allowed.

What should I do?

Comment: You can verify the correctness of your data structure accessing methods with a simple dump. You can print out the array with: `{{ dump(user.getRoles()) }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure 'name' even exists? Tried doing a `{{ dump(user.getRoles()) }}`? What you're doing looks fine to me.

I constructed a similar method in my user object:

```
public function getTest() {

    return [['name' => 'name1'],['name' => 'name2']];
}
```

And calling that in twig:

```
{{ user.getTest()[0]['name'] }}
```

Prints out 'name1' - so it looks like all twig is doing is telling you the key doesn't exist.

Comment: I fixed it by doing: `{{ attribute(attribute(user.getRoles(), 0), 'name') }}`